# Vaio vpccw1s1: Reinstalled wireless drivers now radio does not turn on

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, sony-vaio

Today, I had some minor problems with the wireless drivers so I uninstalled the wireless  drivers. Just after that, I reinstalled them using the ones I already had by default in my machine. Then I did an upgrade of the drivers to the version 13.0.0.107 (using vaio update) and now VAIO smart network won't turn the wireless on. I press the option to turn it on but nothing happens. Anyway, the LED in the laptop is turned on, so the radio seem to have energy.

- I already tried restarting the PC multiple times.
- I already reinstalled the wireless device multiple times.

I keep pressing the option to turn on the wireless in Vaio Smart Network but nothing happens. Only works with bluetooth.

There must be something I'm missing but I don't know what.

After doing what @brock029 asked, I have the following conclusions:

- Before the reinstall, I was being unable to properly connect to wireless networks. It was failing the handshake protocol repeatedly.
- If I uninstall and use only the default drivers, all is the same.

While I don't get answers, I'll try other approaches...

UPDATE:
I was being unable to solve it, so I just used the last possible solution I could think of. System restore. It solved that problem but came with some secondary problems. I'll be able to solve them in the next hours, though... Thanks your your help

Comment: I'll assume you're using Windows. How do things look when you look at Device Manager?

Comment: Yeah, it's windows. no errors. All is ok. Drivers are properly installed.

Comment: @LeeTaylor . . ^

Comment: Being unable to solve it, I just used the last possible solution. System restore. It solved that problem but came with some secondary problems. I'll be able to solve them in the next hours... Thanks your your help

Answer (score 0):

You could try to temporarily disable the VAIO Smart Network software and then enable WLAN AutoConfig (Windows Vista & 7 native wireless service).  By following this [Ehow guide on disabling VAIO Smart Network](http://www.ehow.com/how_7196036_disable-vaio-smart-network.html) and then this [Guide on how to enable WLAN Autoconfig Service](http://www.home-network-help.com/wlan-autoconfig-service.html).  This way you might be able to narrow it down if its a driver issue, software messing up, or something else.

Also what problems were you having with your wireless before you uninstalled the drivers?  If you go back to the original ones and dont upgrade it do you still have problems with it?

Comment: Done. Nothing has changed from the user POV. I already had Wlansvc running. What now? (I'll update my question up there right now)